# Angular Unit Test: Override the Provider

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have following in Providers array.

```
     {
        provide: EnrolmentService,
        useValue: {
           swapToken: jasmine.createSpy('swapToken')
        }
     }
```

I need the jasmine spy for swapToken method of Enrolment service everywhere except in one test case where I need to make actual call to the swapToken() method.

Can someone please suggest how to override the above provider for a specific unit test?

Comment: Is this provider on the `NgComponent` decorator, or `NgModule` decorator?

Comment: @Pieterjan Apologies. I didn't understand what you are asking. Enrolment service is injected in the constructor of a component and I am writing test cases for that component

Comment: @Pieterjan I got it now! The provider is on a NgModule decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't read the code thoroughly. So I assume the provider you posted is specified in the `spec` file on the `configureTestingModule` method

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [...],
    providers: [{
        provide: EnrolmentService,
        useValue: {
           swapToken: jasmine.createSpy('swapToken')
        }
     }]
});
```

or a `...TestingModule` which you're importing in the specfile module

```
@Injectable()
public class EnrollmentTestingService {
}
```

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [{
        provide: EnrollmentService,
        useClass: EnrollmentTestingService
    }]
})
public class EnrollmentTestingModule {
}
```

since you're creating a mock with `jasmine`.

I think all you have to do is import this `EnrollmentTestingModule` into almost all your testingmodules (spec), and in the one specfile that's the exception, simply specify the provider

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [...],
    providers: [{
        provide: EnrolmentService,
        useValue: {
           swapToken: /* something else here */
        }
     }]
});
```